# Align <td> element in table using CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

This might sound odd, but doing this:

```
<table id="MyTableID">
     <tr>
         <td align="center">
                <div id="1">
                   Content
               </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Aligns "Content" to the center, but:

```
<table id="MyTableID">
     <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div id="1">
                   Content
               </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Aligns it to the left.

I've read many posts about using `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`, and also extracted the style to a css file. Nothing of this seems to work for me.

Does anyone know why? what am I doing wrong? I'm using Firefox 19.

Comment: Both center for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ttfSk/. Note that `align="center"` is deprecated.

Comment: Same for me. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Are you trying to center the content in the td or center the td itself ?

Comment: Never start ID with a number, try using some string.

Comment: Aaah, sorry. Works for me in ff19.

Comment: @pd4627 thanks, I was just setting an Id in the example and the first key I found was 1 XD

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, I don't but maybe is another css that is in conflict, but the code doesn't work in the webpage I'm improving :S And yes, I'm trying to validate the page html 5, that's why I'm changing ;) With the div inside it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the misunderstanding here is that in using traditional html alignment you declare the style of alignment in the parent element.

```
<td align="center">
    <!-- Centered stuff in here -->
</td>
```

You shouldn't use text-align for aligning block-level elements. Also, when using block elements you typically want to apply that style to that specific node and then align using margins.

```
<td>
    <div style="width:100px;margin:0 auto"></div>
</td>
```

That being said throwing block elements in tables is never really a good idea. Tables are typically reserved for HTML emails and tabular data. Most modern web products are structured with divs/spans using CSS.

Comment: This worked! It is needed to use the the <div> inside the <td>, or change the div css. Without the <div> it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianVielma my pleasure, please mark as answered so this question doesn't appear as unresolved. =)